# What is wrong in my C code for a program about strcmp()?

Tags: c, string, c-strings, strcmp

I am writing a program for comparing two strings without using strcmp(). But, am unable to get my desired result.
Here is the code for my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
   int i,j;
   char a[90],b[90];
   printf("Enter the first string:");
   scanf("%s", &a[90]);
   printf("Enter the second string:");
   scanf("%s", &b[90]);
   for ( i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && b[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if (a[i] == b[i]) {
         /* code */
         printf("Equal %d \n", a[i]-b[i]);
continue;
      } if (a[i] > b[i]) {
         /* code */
         printf("ai is big %d \n", a[i]-b[i]);
         break;
      }
      if (a[i] < b[i]) {
         /* code */
         printf("%d bi is the biggest \n", a[i]-b[i]);
         break;
      }

   }


   return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program in my terminal the compiler takes the input strings and then stops. I tried it a lot but am unable to figure it out. Can anyone help me out...!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by passing the one after the last element to `scanf`? Except of undefined behavior...

Comment: Your buffer is 90 units large. But you use zero based indexing to access the parts in the buffer. So you have to use 0 to 89. Not 1 to 90.

Comment: Don't use the C++ tag for questions about C.

Comment: Don't take the address of the last element of your char array. C strings (empty ones) need at least 1 element to store the null terminator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of your first array is `a`, not `a[90]`.

Similarly, the name of your second array is `b`, not `b[90]`.

The expressions `a[90]` and `b[90]` name one element after the end of `a` and `b`.

So, by writing `&a[90]` and `&b[90]` you are instructing `scanf` to write *just after* each array, which is very bad and wrong.

You probably meant `&a[0]` and `&b[0]`?

However, `scanf` is very dangerous and you should not be using it at all.

Comment: Thnxxx I got the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The expressions '&a[90]' and '&b[90]' each generate the addresses of the last entries in arrays a and b.  That means you are reading the strings into unallocated stack memory, not into the arrays.  You need to just use plain 'a' and 'b' in the scanf() calls.

If you are now wondering "How does scanf know to limit the strings to 90 characters?", the answer is IT NEVER DOES.  Scanf assumes the caller has provided enough buffer space for the entered string (including terminating null-char).  If you really need to be able to enter arbitrarily long strings, you will have to perform much more sophisticated buffer management.  If you only want to ensure less than 90 characters are ever entered, you need to drop down to getting one character at a time (and I believe you will have to explicitly check for the terminating newline) and count them to ensure you don't overflow the buffer.

Comment: `&a[90]` in fact evaluates to a pointer *just past the end* of array `a`, not to its last element.  Similarly `&b[90]`.  As for how `scanf()` can know to limit the size of the strings, that can be communicated to it via width components in the field descriptors in the format string (e.g. "%89s").  You're correct, though, that if you don't specify the width then `scanf()` doesn't know; this is an important point.

Comment: _"The expressions '&a[90]' and '&b[90]' each generate the addresses of the last entries in arrays a and b."_ No they don't

Comment: Safer alternatives to `scanf("%s")` include `scanf("%89s")` (though you'll want to check, perhaps with `%n`, whether you ran out of space), `fgets()` (but not `gets()`) and (on POSIX.1-2008 systems) `scanf("%ms")`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with the given code in question.

## issues

1- Unused variable `j`.

2- While getting the string from user, in `scanf` `a[90]` and `b[90]` is used that means string will be stored from 90th array index. This can lead to some memory issues and output will have some garbage values.

Its is good to use `a[0]` and `b[0]` in `scanf`. We can use array name in `scanf` as array name points to the starting address of array.

```
scanf ("%s", a); 

scanf ("%s", b);
```

## Correct code :

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{

        int i;
        char a[90],b[90];
        printf("Enter the first string:");
        scanf("%s", a);
        printf("Enter the second string:");
        scanf("%s", b);
        for ( i = 0; a[i] != '\0' || b[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                if (a[i] == b[i]) {
                        /* code */
                        printf("Equal %d \n", a[i]-b[i]);
                        continue;
                } if (a[i] > b[i]) {
                        /* code */
                        printf("a is big %d \n", a[i]-b[i]);
                        break;
                }
                if (a[i] < b[i]) {
                        /* code */
                        printf("%d b is the biggest \n", a[i]-b[i]);
                        break;
                }

        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[90]` will lead to garbage values, if you are lucky. This is undefined behavior. Also, `a` decays to the address of the first _element_ of `a`, not to the address of `a`. `&a[0]` is a pointer to `char`, and `a` decays to this value. `&a` is a pointer to an array of `char`s, with type `(char *)[90]`. Perhaps this is what you meant, but this could have been more clear.